# Shared framework between iOS and tvOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, cross-platform, tvos

I am trying to build a crossplatform framework that can be embeded both in and iOS and a tvOS application.

This framework does NOT contain anything related to UI but is a wrapper around CoreBluetooth.

[image]

**What I explored ?**

It compiles when I set the base sdk to tvOS, and when I set the base sdk to iOS. But I do not know how to make it work for both

[image]

Do you know how I could have both at the same time ?

Thanks

Stan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create two different targets in your xcodeproj, one for iOS, and one for tvOS.

[image]

Then simply add both target as Target Membership for your swift files.

[image]

Comment: It is not the most beautiful way of doing it but I did not find any other solution... Thanks